# Get an array of Angular's DOM elements

Tags: angularjs

I have directive with link. Inside link I want to find all buttons and put the into an array:

```
var buttons = angular.element(element[0].querySelectorAll('button'));
```

If I consol.log buttons I got some weird array

```
[button.ng-binding, button, button, button]
```

Which looks like this when I expand

```
R(5)
0:buttonng-binding
1:button
2:button
3:button
4:button
length:5
__proto__:Object(0)
```

My problem is I can't access any items inside buttons `buttons[0]` is undefined same if I try `buttons(0)`

If I do

```
var buttons = [];
buttons = angular.element(element[0].querySelectorAll('button'));
```

I got some wired array which I can't get any items from.

So my question is, how to query my directive and store all buttons inside an array?

Comment: The documentation of angular.element() says: "Wraps a raw DOM element or HTML string". The documentation of querySelectorAll() says: "Returns a non-live NodeList of all elements". So you're passing something to angular.element() that it does not support. I suggest you read some documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll

Comment: Can you share more of your code?